# Low Variables not allowing new cell or entries when using Matrix

Tags: ee2, matrix, low-variables

I'm using Low Variables v235 with Expression Engine Core. I'm trying to create a new variable which uses Matrix, but something isn't right. Matrix won't allow me to add a new column. There are no + signs below the cells, and the formatting doesn't look quite right. When I tried to create a new entry, the line 'No rows exist yet. Create the first one.' appears, but won't let me click on Create the first one, even though it appears as a link. The cursor remains as a text selector, rather than changing to the 'finger' like it should if it were a link.

I uploaded Low Variables again just in case there was something wrong (both system and theme files) with the first installation, but i'm having the same problem.

I've used LV before, with Matrix, and haven't had this problem. I just don't know what's wrong this time.

Comment: can you check in the firebug console if there are any javascript error messages?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I did that and it helped me realise that I stupidly loaded the matrix theme files outside of the third party folder. All sorted now. Thanks.

Comment: no prob :) Glad it helped.